# What does the illusion of movement mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've seen it in various definitions about movies and animation, but what does the ''illusion of movement'' mean? Some people think that live-action movies and animation are one single entity but it's not one single entity, what does the '' illusion of movement'' mean?

Comment: A movie or video is a sequence of still images. If you show them to the human eye fast enough, (quicker than 24 in a second) the brain has the illusion that the things depicted in the images are really moving. This is true whether the images are photographs or drawn images (like cartoons or animations).

Comment: Although the pictures aren't really moving, you're actually seeing a sequence of still images at a certain rate, Every image medium is still images, and movies, TV shows and videos is a sequence of still images displayed a certain rate. People who live under a rock may think it's one continuous entity, but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following text about illusion of movement on Future Learn [1](https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/explore-animation/0/steps/12222):

> **Persistence of vision: how does animation work?**
>
> **How does persistence of vision work in animation?**
>
> **Animation works by using an optical illusion. By presenting a sequence of still images in quick enough succession, the viewer interprets them as a continuous moving image. This is the same principle that enables live action film making and projection to work. Film theorists often refer to this illusion of movement as the persistence of vision.**
>
> **Persistence of vision works because the human eye and brain can only process 10 to 12 separate images per second, retaining an image for up to a fifteenth of a second. If a subsequent image replaces it in this period of time it will create the illusion of continuity.**
>
> **The use of animation techniques to create moving images predates conventional cinema. Devices like the phenakistoscope (disk pictured above) and the zoetrope used the basic principles of animation to provide entertainment in the 19th century.**

Comment: This isn't the same illusion as that of TV/movies.

Comment: Better, yup. . .